# Android app: mkdir() fails on Google Nexus 7

Tags: java, android, google-nexus

I am trying to create a folder with mkdir() with an app on a Google Nexus 7 tablet. After that I am saving an image in that folder.

The relevant code is:

```
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdir()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and the log says: "Oops! Failed create userImages".

**What I have tried so far:**

- testing the App on a Samsung Galaxy S3 mini with Android 4.1.2 and it worked. (-> it seems to be device specific)
- Adding the permission
  `< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >`
  to the AndroidManifest.xml
- using mkdirs() instead of mkdir()
- the function

  ```
  //Check SD card state
  String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
  if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state) || !Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error: external storage is read only or unavailable");
  } else {
      Log.d(TAG, "External storage is not read only or unavailable");
  }
  ```

  gives "External storage is *not* read only or unavailable".

**My code:**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.hbksaar.bubbles">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Does anybody have a clue, why it is not possible for me to create that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Android OS you used ? If you run on Android 6.0, it maybe due to you app donot have *Storage* permission, go to *Settings* -> *Apps* -> *Your App* -> *Permissions* to double check your app have *Storage* permission. Grant *Storage* permission if not granted yet.

Try to log the full path of *mediaStorageDir* to make sure it is a correct path on SD Card.

Also try to use mkdirs() to create non-exist parent directories.

Comment: When I change the permission settings it does work! Thanks! But I want to have the permission to write by default, e.g. when installing the app or at least the user should be asked, when I am trying to write, how is this possible?

Comment: checkout request permission at run time: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

if the android version is marshmallow then the permission check is dynamic.

Please use ContextCompat to chek permission.

Comment: Checked it with "ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);" and the result was PERMISSION_DENIED. Why is the static permission != the runtime permission? What can I do?

Comment: check this out.      http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html